# Having a portrait label in a landscape view

Tags: ios, xib

I've created a .xib with a landscape orientation UIView.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want a UILabel running vertically along the side with text reading from bottom of the view to the top, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Is that possible?

Image to show what I mean

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rotate and then translate it to put it where you want it.  Rotation happens around the center of the label which is why you then need to translate it.
If you laid out the text label with the upper left corner where you wanted it to end up (i.e. the displayed label looks like it rotates around the upper left corner point of the label), you'd use code something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_2);
    CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(floor(-self.label.bounds.size.width / 2), floor(-self.label.bounds.size.width / 2)));
    self.label.transform = transform2;
}
```

You might need to adjust the translation values slightly to get what you want, but you definitely want them to be integers (which I've done with floor) so the label is crisp.

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar but I wasn't able to get it in the right position.  In the end I kept the old frame and then rotated before setting the frame back again, this kept the label in the same position as I had set it up in the xib.

Comment: When you think about a translation, think about what it takes to move the center point of the laid-out label to the center of where you want it to be.  In my example, the label was laid out along the bottom of the view and I wanted it vertically along the left side.  In that case subtracting half the label width from both x and y moves the center to the left edge and up enough that the label starts at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. You need to do a transform.

```
yourlabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
```